# List of transaction hashes in chronological order?

Tags: monerod, daemon, rpc

Is there a daemon RPC call to get a list of all the latest transactions and their hashes?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [get_block](https://ww.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_block) which includes includes the tx hashes (`tx_hashes`) in that block. You can then use [get_transactions](https://ww.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_transactions) if you need further details on the transactions.

Comment: But the get_transaction wont give me the time when the transaction has been added to the block.

Comment: It's added to the block at the timestamp of the block (as returned in get_block). If you want the time it was added to the tx pool, you'd have to check [get_transaction_pool](https://ww.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_transaction_pool). But honestly, time added to block is really all thats important.